# ASP.net Change Checkbox ID on Server Side

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

The problem I have is the following,
I have a table with records from a database Loaded in my html Table.
I want to add a checkbox on each Line with their UniqueID number from the database.

[image]

My code to do do this

```
<td class="auto-style172" style="vertical-align: top">
  <asp:CheckBox ID="checkbox1" runat="server" Text=" " ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
  <%checkbox1.ID = line.QuoteLine%>
</td>
```

This code works except it doesn't change the first Checkbox id. How Can I make it work anyway will do!
Thanks!

And this doesn't work

```
<td class="auto-style172" style="vertical-align: top">
  <asp:CheckBox ID="<%line.QuoteLine%>" runat="server" Text=" " ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
</td>
```

Comment: Are you using a repeater to populate this table? Have you tried to add ClientIDMode="Static" on the CheckBox definition? or even change <%line.Quoteline%> for <%#line.Quoteline%>?

Comment: This is done in a foreach loop not a repeater. I can try the client Idmode. <%#line.Quoteline%> didn't work

Comment: ClientModeId didn't do anything different Thanks for the suggestion tho

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but wouldn't this be really easy to do in a GridView?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Steve but I am not use to using asp controls As I'am used to be a php developer. But you are right I could use a grid view but is there a way by using a table or a repeater?